# Using MINIF/MAXIF with strings containing numbers?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, fractions

I want to find the minimum number with given conditions(is writer and is under probation), the below code works if `D` contains numbers, but how do I do it if the number is a part of a string, like a fraction for example? Like how do I use this formula if numbers in `D` look like "1/8", "31/688", "21/33", etc?

```
=MINIFS(D3:D1007, A3:A1007, "Writer", C3:C1007, "Probation")
```

I already have another formula that I use that calculates a decimal value given the fraction, If the fraction is in cell `D21` then it would look like this:

```
=left(D21,find("/",D21)-1)/(right(D21,len(D21)-find("/",D21)))
```

but how do I apply this kind of formula in a minif/maxif?

[I have attached a picture to show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6JCr.png), what I'm trying to do is to put a formula in the passed/total column of package stats(probation), and it will get the lowest passed/total value out of the ones with that package name and importance level. as you can see, the entire writer package's pass rate is 5/8 because the lowest pass rate out of the writer package 5/8 is the lowest pass rate out people with package=writers and importance = probation. But at the moment I have to enter the 5/8s manually, I want it to be able to get it automatically using the formula I'm trying to figure out above.

[image: I have attached a picture to show what I mean]

Comment: What do you mean by "*number is a part of a string*"? Excel knows how to interpret fractions.

Comment: I am using google sheets so I guess they can't interpret fractions, but just assume the string is like "1#3" or something that excel cannot parse, where there are numbers in a string of a particular format, how do I get those numbers?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Google Sheets can almost certainly interpret fractions.  Some sample data, and example of the expected output, would help.

Comment: ^ Share a sample sheet too if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF((A3:A="writer")*(C3:C="probation"), 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "\d+")/REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "/(\d+)"), D3:D), )))
```

[image: 0]

or to return fraction:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(MIN(IF((A3:A="writer")*(C3:C="probation"), 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "\d+")/REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "/(\d+)"), D3:D), )), 
 {IF((A3:A="writer")*(C3:C="probation"), 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "\d+")/REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "/(\d+)"), D3:D), ), D3:D}, 2, 0))
```

[image: e]

also make sure fractions are formatted as **plain text** not date

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was trying to do!

Comment: Just wondering, how exactly would one go about setting multiple conditions? for example. what if I wanted to target importance level of "probation" and "N/A"? I have tried putting a OR in that portion of the IF but it was not effective.

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF((A3:A="writer")*((C3:C="probation")+(C3:C="n/a")), 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "\d+")/REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "/(\d+)"), D3:D), )))`

Comment: or: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF((A3:A="writer")*(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(C3:C), "probation|n/a")), IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "\d+")/REGEXEXTRACT(D3:D, "/(\d+)"), D3:D), )))`